# Perl module to check whether a string was created by inserting text into another string

Tags: perl, perl-module, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

### Problem

I have two strings `$base` and `$succ` and want to check whether `$succ` can be created from `$base` by inserting arbitrary strings at arbitrary positions.

Some examples, written as isSucc(`$base`, `$succ`):

- isSucc("abc", "abcX") is **true**, since we can insert X at the end of abc.
- isSucc("abc", "XabYcZ") is **true**, since we can insert **X**ab**Y**c**Z**.
- isSucc("abc", "abX") is **false**, since c was deleted.
- isSucc("abc", "cab") is **false**, since c (the one at the end of abc) was deleted.
- isSucc("abc", "cabc") is **true**, since we can insert c at the beginning of abc.
- isSucc("", "anything") is **true**, since we just have to insert "anything".

We can assume, that `$base` and `$succ` do not contain any (vertical) withespace. Usually we have `length($base) < length($succ) < 1000`. Good performance is not critical but would be nice to have.

I already know one way to implement `isSucc`*.

### Question

- Is there a perl-module that defines something similar to `isSucc`?
- Does someone has an easier/faster/alternative implementation* of `isSucc`?

### * My Approach

Compute the edit/[Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) with a custom cost model (*cost(Insertion)=0, cost(Deletion)=cost(substitution)=1*). Then check whether the edit distance is 0.

### Comparing the Answers

I wanted to compare the three solutions [*loop*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40564309/6770384), *greedy matching*, and *non-greedy matching*, but the matching methods often took more than 100 times as long as the loop solution so I aborted the tests. Nevertheless – or perhaps exactly for that reason – we have a clear winner: The loop solution.
Big thanks to Christoffer Hammarström.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sub is_subsequence {
    my ($needles, $haystack) = @_;
    my $found = 0;
    for my $needle (split '', $needles) {               # for each character $needle in $needles
        $found = 1 + index $haystack, $needle, $found;  # find it after the previous one in $haystack
        return 0 unless $found;                         # return false if we can't
    }
    return 1;                                           # return true if we found all $needles in $haystack
}
```

---

```
use Test::More tests => 6;              # 1..6
is 1, is_subsequence("abc", "abcX");    # ok 1
is 1, is_subsequence("abc", "XabYcZ");  # ok 2
is 0, is_subsequence("abc", "abX");     # ok 3
is 0, is_subsequence("abc", "cab");     # ok 4
is 1, is_subsequence("abc", "cabc");    # ok 5
is 1, is_subsequence("", "anything");   # ok 6
```

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. I mean, yes, you *can* do this by finding the longest common subsequence and then comparing; but the longest common subsequence problem involves dynamic programming (hence extra storage and so on) and quadratic time, whereas the OP's problem can be solved with a greedy algorithm in linear time.

Comment: @ruakh Oops, seems like I missed the obvious and fast solution. Many thanks to the two of you!

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström such a simple solution, nice one. I found it a little hard to work out though as `is_subsequence` through me off since `abc` is not a subsequence of `XabYcZ` for example. Might I suggest renaming the sub to something like `is_expandable_into` ?

Comment: @PeterR: `abc` is a subsequence of `XabYcZ`, but it is not a substring. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence which says "The subsequence should not be confused with substring"

Answer (score 1):

```
sub isSucc {
 my($base, $succ)=@_;
 $base=~s/./quotemeta($&).".*?"/ge;
 $succ =~ $base;
}
```

Create regular expression `a.*?b.*?c.*?` for string `abc` and test `$succ`.

Answer (score -1):

```perl
{
    my $last_base;
    my $last_re;

    sub is_succ {
        my ($base, $succ) = @_;
        my $re;

        if ($base eq $last_base) {
            $re = $last_re;
        }
        else {
            $last_base = $base;
            $last_re = $re = join(".*?", map { quotemeta($_) } split("", $base));
        }

        return $succ =~ /$re/;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use a non-greedy quantifier `.*?` to avoid catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: @nwellnhof: Changing to non-greedy quantifiers doesn't in general result in an improvement in backtracking. For some strings, greedy quantifiers may produce a faster result.

Comment: @Borodin In this specific case, greedy quantifers are dangerous. Try for yourself: `perl -MBenchmark=:all -e"cmpthese(100000, { greedy => sub { 'aaaaaaaaaa' =~ /a.*a.*a.*a.*a.*a.*a.*a.*a.*a/ }, lazy => sub { 'aaaaaaaaaa' =~ /a.*?a.*?a.*?a.*?a.*?a.*?a.*?a.*?a.*?a/ } });"`

Comment: @nwellnhof: That is an artificial test case designed to exacerbate the problem. Try it with the OP's own data.

Comment: @nwellnhof: `perl -MBenchmark=:all -e"cmpthese(1E7, { greedy => sub { 'axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxaaaa' =~ /a.*a.*a.*a.*a.*a.*a.*a.*a.*a/ }, lazy => sub { 'axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxaaaa' =~ /a.*?a.*?a.*?a.*?a.*?a/ } });"`

Comment: @Borodin I don't see what you're getting at. Your example is basically a tie between lazy and greedy quantifiers on my machine. For the type of the regex in question, lazy quantifiers should be at least as fast as greedy ones, but they avoid pathological cases. Even with real world data like `banana`, they can be considerably faster.

Answer (score -1):

Power of regex can make this task quite simple

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $needle = 'abc';

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say "'$needle' in '$_'" if search_needle($needle,$_);
}

say "'' in 'Anything'" if search_needle('','Anything');

sub search_needle {
    my $needle = shift;
    my $haystack = shift;

    my $re = join('.*?', split('',$needle));

    return $haystack =~ /$re/;

}

__DATA__
abcX
XabYcZ
abX
cab
cabc
```

Output

```
'abc' in 'abcX'
'abc' in 'XabYcZ'
'abc' in 'cabc'
'' in 'Anything'
```

Comment: Note that you can't blindly add characters from `needle` to a regex. You need to escape the meta characters first, as was already done over three years ago by another answer here.